# How to simulate Pythons's dict "items()" method for Java's HashMaps?

Tags: java, python, hashmap

I know I should learn how to program efficiently in Java and stop thinking it is Python; but the problem is that this kind of thing is turning out to be a small nightmare in Java.

I have the following function in Python that takes a string as an argument:

```
def decodeL(input):
L = []
for i in range(len(input)):
    for j in x.items(): // Where "x" is the Dictionary outside the function.
        if input[i].lower() in j[0]:
            L.append(j[1])
return L
```

Ignoring the functionality of the function itself, what makes it work so well is the "items()" method, which returns me tuples inside of a list. As you can see, I play with these tuples acessing its own indexes.

In Java this is a very unpleasant problem.

```
static ArrayList items(HashMap hashTarget) {
    ArrayList L = new ArrayList();
    Set<String> keys = hashTarget.keySet();
    Collection<Object> values = hashTarget.values();

    for (int i = 0; i < hashTarget.size(); i++) {
        L.add(keys);
        L.add(values);
    }

    return L;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to implement my own "items()" method and I failed miserably; since there is no tuples natively in Java, this is really messing up with my brain :). I can't intercalate the keys and values in the same way that Python does so beautifully; therefore, I can't create the Java Version of that "decodeL" function, which is my final goal.

So, that's it; another random "challenge" for you guys.

Comment: I coded that function in Python and it was the best solution I found for it. I'm not an experienced programer, so I belive in you completely if you say that that isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough, it's not an issue, it's just extremely hard to read as it doesn't *feel* like Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has already implemented this for you in the way of the `Map.entrySet()` method.

```
for(Map.Entry<K, V> j : x.entrySet()) {
    V val = j.getValue(); // j[1]
    K key = j.getKey();   // j[0]
}
```

Comment: I just upvote yours, and remove mine, since they are the same idea. and you beat me in about 20seconds...

Comment: I thank you both! That will do, I can handle it now that I have this.